# Edit variables from object in ArrayList?

Tags: java

```
public void setPunt(int index){
    if(index >= 0 && index < PuntenLijst.size()){
        x = 3;
        y = 5;
    }
}
```

I have got an array of object instances in an array list called PuntenLijst. With this method I want to use the index parameter to locate the object in the ArrayList and set the variables x and y that are defined in the object instance to 3 and 5.

This is how far I have gotten. Is there anyone who can help me out?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry but this is a little vague. Are you just saying you want, `PutenLijst.get(index)`.x=3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a setX and setY method in your object. Use them to change the value.

```
public void setPunt(int index){
if(index >= 0 && index < PuntenLijst.size()){
    PuntenLijst.get(index).setX(3);
    .... setY(5);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setPunt(int index){
if(index >= 0 && index < PuntenLijst.size()){

  (ClassOfObjects)PuntenLijst.get(index).x=3;
  (ClassOfObjects)PuntenLijst.get(index).y=5;


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask the list for the `Punt` stored at the given index: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29.

Then use the methods provided by the `Punt` class to modify its internal state. My guess is that it has a `setX()` and a `setY()` methods (it should have those if you need to change its coordinates, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```
ArrayList<Object> PuntenLijst= new ArrayList<>(); // your arrayList

public void setPunt(int index){
    if(index >= 0 && index < PuntenLijst.size()){
        Object myObj = PuntenLijst.get(index);
        myObj.setX(3);
        myObj.setY(5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs on ArrayList http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

In your case, you'd want to do the following:

```
   if(index >= 0 && index < puntenLijst.size()){
        puntenLijst.get(index).x = 3;
        puntenLijst.get(index).y = 5;
    }
```

Note the following changes:
puntenLijst should not be capitalized.  x and y must be public variables in order to assign values like above.