# Changing a variable in an Object from an ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, object, arraylist, coordinates, path-finding

I am currently trying to create a pathfinding method for my grid based game based on the A* method algorithm. However I am having a basic problem with manipulating variables within my PathNode class instances:

```
public void AStarPathfinding(PathNode snakeHead, PathNode foodLocation) {

    System.out.println(food.xFood);
    System.out.println(food.yFood);

        openNodes.add(snakeHead);

        int xHead = (int) snakeSegments.get(0);
        int yHead = (int) snakeSegments.get(1);


        snakeHead.xCoordinate = (int) xHead;
        snakeHead.yCoordinate = (int) yHead;
        foodLocation.xCoordinate = (int) food.xFood;
        foodLocation.yCoordinate = (int) food.yFood;
```

however I am receiving null-point exception errors:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ArtificialSnake.AStarPathfinding(ArtificialSnake.java:136)
```

which is this line:

```
snakeHead.xCoordinate = (int) xHead;
```

The idea is to set the startNode(snakeHead) to the current snake head's location.... but as suggested above I cannot work out how to modify the xCoordinate variable in the snakeHead instance of the PathNode class.

Looking at another question: [Edit variables from object in ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923474/edit-variables-from-object-in-arraylist)

It suggests using setters, I have tired this however I still get null point exception errors.

Note: the Thread2 is the gameLoop thread separate from the Swing U.I, the class that this pathfinding method is in is part of the same thread.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The error seems that `snakeHead` is null

Comment: That means `snakeHead` is `null` when the `NullPointerException` occurs. Debug your code, find out why it's `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you receive a null pointer error on the line `snakeHead.xCoordinate = (int) xHead;` this means that `snakeHead` is `null`, check that `null` isn't being passed into the method.
If your wonderhy why a null pointer error doesn't occur at `openNodes.add(snakeHead);` it is because `null` can be added to some java collections, they don't all try to perform any operations on what you pass to them (those that do may call `hashCode()`, `equals()` or `compare()` depending on the collection type and  it's implementation).

When you pass objects between methods and into collections/arrays you are making shallow copies (You are passing a reference to the object) so any changes you make to the object, will be visible in every other place you've passed the reference.

The only way to make a deep copy of an object (so that changes don't affect other references to the object) is to copy every member variable of the object (some classes may provide a clone method that does this).

Comment: I see, this is a clear gap (as I am still quite new.) in my knowledge as I am trying to adapt a similar alogrithm that uses HashMap instead of ArrayList (however I would like to use ArrayList to achieve the same goal). One final part of the question - I have an ArrayList inside my object called neighbors (so neighboring nodes to current PathNode). I am having a nullpoint exception again for line "for (PathNode neighbor : current.neighbors) {" my problem with previous part was that  I only did "Public PathNode snakeHead" instead of "PathNode snakeHead = new PathNode" ... but doesnt work for nei

Comment: Are you sure that `snakeHead` is being initialised (`new PathNode()`) before your using it?

Comment: Also, if you are interested in path finding, you should look at Dijkstras algorithm. I have also come across an innovative path finding algorithm which performs really well in certain scenarios [Jump Point Search](http://harablog.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/jump-point-search/). I've done a fair bit of code with graph search/path finding ;)

Comment: Well the snakeHead's xCoordinate is now 300 as it should be, but I believe the problem now is trying to initilize, reference or read the "ArrayList<PathNode> neighbor = new ArrayList()" that is inside the Pathnode class of snakeHead (so it sees the xCoordinates ect). as far as pathfinding code goes I'm using a template to learn from as my ability to adapt psuedocode at the moment is poor, so learning through implementing/modifying existing code (with permissions ofc).

Comment: Is your code short enough to drop in a pastebin so I can have a play with it for you? Don't worry about reusing and learning from other peoples code, everyone does it. Just don't try to commercialise other peoples code without permission.

Comment: I can give you the classes involved maybe you can notice the problem, I might be missing something very simple! like I said though I havn't been doing this long as you might notice from the code but here is the link http://pastebin.com/u2NjE430 thank you for your help :)

Comment: From looking at that code a few things stand out, in your AStar method your adding `snakeHead` to `openNodes` twice (it is a list, not a set so it will allow duplicates), you are never clearing your `openNodes` and other lists, and you are never setting the neighbours on a `pathNode`. I didn't get much further than that, any/all of those are reasons that can make your search fail for various reasons. Personally I would start by separating the path code from the game and trying to implement a basic console application that can find paths in small graphs (This would give you a simpler start).

Comment: Yea that is likely a good idea, while the first 2 suggestions are simple to change, how would you suggest I set the neighbor on a pathnode? after that I think everything is answered! Again thanks for all the help you have given :) I will try an easier graphic to start with.

Comment: To perform your search you need to represent your graph (presumably you do this by having each of your path nodes hold a shallow copy of their neighbouring path nodes).

The way I would do this for a non-symmetrical graph would be to create the links as the graph is built. However if your graph is a NxN grid. I would probably use some basic arithmetic and a HashMap to store all nodes in a global collection so they can be accessed by their coordinate, this would allow you to calculate neighbours, rather than having to link them.

Comment: If the cost of traversing between nodes isn't regular you will need to create a list of link objects or a cost function.